# When I try to build for production this error comes up

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

When I try to build for production, this error comes up. I'm using React Native Firebase. This error happens on android.

Here is the error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-firebase_app:generateReleaseRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-firebase_app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-release.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-symbol-with-package-name, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=release, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
      > Could not find react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-release.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0).
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-native/0.71.0-rc.0/react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-release.aar
```

Here are my packages

```
[tag:    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^16.4.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.4.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "meilisearch": "^0.29.1",
    "native-base": "^3.4.21",
    "picomatch": "^2.3.1",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.3",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^8.2.1",
    "react-native-navigation-bar-color": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.5.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0"]
```

If you can help, thanks!

I have tried everything I could find online =(

I have also tried `npx jetify`

Comment: This might help https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

Answer (score 18):

Try this

add these lines into android/build.gradle File

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()

         exclusiveContent {
           filter {
               includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
           }
           forRepository {
               maven {
                   url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
               }
           }
       }
       
       }
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug with react native, a fix has been released.

Check https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

Comment: Lost a whole day with this problem. Finally, once only, I actually am not at fault for a bug lmao

Answer (score 2):

You can check this link to know what exactly the problem is:
[No matching variant of com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0 was found](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210)

Solution 1:

Just update your react native version to 0.71 and npm install.

Solution 2:

I was using react native version 0.69.4 and this code helped me to fix it by adding into my android/build.gradle file.

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()

     exclusiveContent {
       filter {
           includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
       }
       forRepository {
           maven {
               url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
           }
       }
   }
   
   }
```

Hope this helps you and anyone going through this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix the issue by updating the version of react native to the latest patch.

| Native version | Update to |
| --- | --- |
| 0.70.x | 0.70.5 |
| 0.69.x | 0.69.7 |
| 0.68.x | 0.68.5 |
| 0.67.x | 0.67.5 |
| 0.66.x | 0.66.5 |
| 0.65.x | 0.65.3 |
| 0.64.x | 0.64.4 |
| 0.63.x | 0.63.5 |

Link to the source: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

Comment: i am using 0.71, i upgraded from 0.60, but this error is still there for android when i am running react-native run-android! Any suggestions ?

Comment: if you are using a react native version lower than 0.63, you need to fix it manually please refer to this link to see how to fix it.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210#:~:text=Fix%20for%20older%20react%2Dnative%20(%3C%200.63)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your react-native version in your app/build.gradle matches your version in the package.json:

app/build.gradle

```
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.70.+"
```

package.json

```
"react-native": "0.70.5"
```

this works for me

Answer (score 0):

as the first answer said it's issue in maven central and react-native resolved that here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210....
in package.json file
update react-native by replace this line

```
 "react-native": "0.70.5"
```

then npm install